# Dynamic variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

1. What is the use of Dynamic
   variables?  Any scenarios?
2. Can I attach this value to a
   TextField?

   ```
   var data = "testVariable";
   eval("var temp_" + data + "=123;");
   alert(temp_testVariable);
   ```

Comment: None. Use hash maps (objects).

Comment: Why not use the slightly more acceptable `window['temp_' + data] = '123';`?

Comment: @josh.trow I'd say that that's a lot more than "slightly" more acceptable :-)

Comment: @Pointy: A mere technicality :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221108/how-to-get-random-variables-value-in-javascript/35250618#35250618

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the use of Dyanmic variables? Any Scenarious

For when people haven't heard of objects or arrays.

> Can i attach this value to a TextField?

Yes.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to 2) is 'yes you can'.

However for 1), and overall, you *probably shouldn't be using eval*: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

As another comment and the currently upvoted answer says - either use arrays or a map.