# Variable name - invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I'm kind of new ... so go easy on me. This is what I want to do:

I have variables named:

```
var item1, item2, item3, etc.;
```

I want to use a **For** loop to asign values to the variables. Like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ item + (i+1) = arr[i] }
```

How can I do this without getting the *Invalid left-hand side in assignment* error?

Thank you.

Comment: If those variables are local, then there is no way to access them "dynamically". Nor should you. Whenever you have variables of the form `prefixX`, then you should use an array or object instead. Since you already seem to have an array, you should change the code that reads `itemX` to work with an array instead. And FYI, `item + (i+1)` will increase `i` by one and add the result to the value of the variable `item`.

Comment: You can't use this `item + (i+1)` for variable names

Comment: I especially like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343596/218196): *"Q: What is the use of Dyanmic variables? A: For when people haven't heard of objects or arrays."*

Comment: @FelixKling Hey, I said take it easy!

Comment: I did, didn't I? Provided you with all sorts of information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make use of a "namespace"/object like this:

```
var app={ item1: undefined, item2: undefined }
for(var i=1; i<3; i+=1) app["item"+i]=666;
console.log(app);
```

In this case, it is no "real" namespacing, but you could use it like that.

For more about Namespacing read this Article from [Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/).

Comment: Using an object is ok, but why talk about namespacing at all? It has nothing to do with this question/answer.

Comment: Yes. As I said, it is no namespacing in the strict sense - more something than an initial step towards namespacing. In a wider sense it behaves like one. On the one hand you could say, "item1" is a property of "app" and on the other hand, you could think of it like "variable »item1« from the namespace »app«".

Comment: Well, yeah, you *can* use objects as namespaces, but this is a bit far fetched here IMO. If I was a beginner, I would find it rather confusing. Here you are using an object as a map, nothing more and nothing less. No need to make it overly complicated.

Comment: Perhaps you're right ;) A bit far fetched.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a global variable, then you can do this:

```
var item1 = 5;
alert(window["item" + 1]);
```